# ARM Template - Improvement - customSetupScriptProperties

Tags: azure-data-factory

In ARM Template generated by ADF for deployment from Azure DevOps, would it be possible to add the parameter

INTEGRATION_RUNTIME_NAME_properties_typeProperties_ssisProperties_customSetupScriptPropertiesblob_**ContainerUri**,

in the same way there is

INTEGRATION_RUNTIME_NAME_properties_typeProperties_ssisProperties_customSetupScriptProperties_**sasToken**

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

IntegrationRuntimeCustomSetupScriptProperties can be used as follows:

```
 "customSetupScriptProperties": {
                        "blobContainerUri": {
                            "value": "-::String"
                        }
                    }
```

And

```
 "customSetupScriptProperties": {
                        "sasToken": {
                            "value": "-::secureString"
                        }
                    }
```

Custom setup script properties for a managed dedicated integration runtime.

[image]

For more details, refer “[Integration Runtimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/integrationruntimes/createorupdate#definitions)”.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Pradeep,

Thank you for your answer. I tried this way, it works. But at every Publish from ADF, the parameter is removed. Could it be implemented natively in the ARM template and ARM Parameters template, as it is the case for Sas Token ?